# Cannot resolve TargetProperty IsHitTestVisable on specified object

Tags: xaml, silverlight

I have a control that I want to enable the property `IsHitTestVisable` as it fades in the opacity. The code compiles, but as soon as the mouse is moved I get the following error: `System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve TargetProperty IsHitTestVisable on specified object.`

```
<local:MotionVisibleControl MinWidth="486" x:Name="MotionActivatedControls" MouseEnterAnimation="
    {StaticResource mouseenter}" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="False">

<Storyboard x:Name="mouseenter">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="MotionActivatedControls">
        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4000000" Value="1" KeySpline="0.495999991893768,0,0.49099999666214,1"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MotionActivatedControls" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisable">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="True" KeyTime="0"/>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've spelled `Visible` wrong.

Try [`IsHitTestVisible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible(v=vs.95).aspx) instead.

Comment: Wow .. how embarrassing! Thanks for catching that. All is working now.